# Asp.net mvc in MS Expression Web (and other web editing tools)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Today I gave in to all the banners asking me to test MS Expression web 2 demo.
After some setup hickups I fired up the thing and immediately encountered a problem:
How do I make this tool work with my asp.net-mvc projects? Actually, how do I make my websites work with ANY tool but visual studio 2008?

Untill now I did everything with VS2008 / Notepad++.
Does anybody have experience with using asp.net-mvc projects in tools like dreamweaver, expression web etc?

Comment: One quick note boris, you should probably edit your question title to replace "MS Blend" with "MS Expression Web." MS Blend is specifically for use with Silverlight & WPF. I clicked on your question because I was interested/confused how you might use MVC together with Blend but found out that wasn't quite what you meant.

Comment: You're wanting to know if it's integrated so you don't have to slice the HTML by hand and put part in the Master template and other parts of the HTML into individual views?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any web tool to edit the HTML+CSS+Javascript side of the site, but you'll need to compile it with VS2008 or MSBuild to run it.